# Limit javax.net.debug=ssl logs

Tags: java, ssl, spring-boot

I have web service written in Java, based on Spring Boot with 2-way SSL (client authentication).

I'm using `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake` option to log information about SSL handshake during requests.

Is it possible to limit/filter those logs? E.x. only log information about successful authentication or authentication failure without all those hexdumps. Because currently every request generates 400 lines of logs.

My goal is to see in logs in production environment if there were any authentication failures and log some basic information about client certificate which came with the request.